# Find the point on a curve a given distance along the curve from another point

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, curve, numerical-integration

I am trying to find a point 'p2' on a curve, and it is 'd' away from point 'p1'.

- The curve is quadratic formula a*x^2 + b*x + c = y
- point p1 is on the curve, let us say (p1x, p1y)
- point p2 is on the curve, but we only know its distance 'along the curve' from p1, which is 'd'. A distance on a curve can be calculated by integrating'(1+(2*a*x+b)^2)^(1/2) dx'. Here, integrating'(1+(2*a*x+b)^2)^(1/2) dx' from p1x to p2x is expectd to have a given number k. p2x is unknown.

I have been using a loop to find the point.

```
from scipy import integrate

def integral(a, b, c, p1x, distance_between_p1_and_p2):
        x = lambda x:(1+(2*a*x+b)**2)**(1/2)
        best_i=0
        p2x=0
        for points_on_curve in range(int(p1x*1000),int((p1x+0.15)*1000),1):
                i,j  = integrate.quad(x,p1x,points_on_curve/1000)
                if abs(i-distance_between_p1_and_p2)<abs(best_i-distance_between_p1_and_p2):
                        best_i=i
                        p2x=points_on_curve/1000
        return p1x+p2x
```

The problem here is it takes so long becuase it begins from p1x and slightly increase the value, calculate the length from p1 to potential p2 and see if it is closer to the target distance_between_p1_and_p2 than the previous one.

Would it be there a better way of programming it?

Comment: sorry i forgot to put library. I only knew integrate in scipy, so i used it. I am not sure scipy can find it when the range is unknown.

Comment: If I can do infinite integration of sqrt(1 + (2*a*x + b)^2) dx, I may be able to do it, but I could not solve it.

Comment: See "finding arc length of curves" in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length), and solve for the analytical form for your class of curves

Comment: Hi Linuxios, that formula let me to have sqrt(1 + (2*a*x + b)^2) dx.. and I am stuck here trying to do infinite integration.

Comment: One idea is, having the integrand, do a sort of binary search of the endpoint space, numerically integrating at each endpoint and checking for the closeness of the arclength to your desired value. Though I have a feeling that integral is probably solvable... maybe ask on Math.SE?

Comment: Or just ask mathematica for a start...

Comment: Mathematica gives the indefinite integral as: `((b + 2*a*x)*Sqrt[1 + (b + 2*a*x)^2] + ArcSinh[b + 2*a*x])/(4*a)`

Comment: closed form is complicated: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt(1+%2B+(2%2Aa%2Ax+%2B+b)%5E2)+dx   Solving for *x* is more complicated.  Can you tolerate an approximate result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working on it and i found two solutions to this.

First, I used sympy.geometry.curve

```
from sympy.geometry.curve import Curve
x = sp. Symbol('x')
a = sp. Symbol('a')
b = sp. Symbol('b')
c = sp. Symbol('c')
start = sp. Symbol('start')
end = sp. Symbol('end')
print('length')
print(Curve((a*x**2+b*x+c, x), (x, start, end)).length)
```

I get this as an output.

```
(end + b/(2*a))*sqrt(4*a**2*(end + b/(2*a))**2 + 1)/2 - (start + b/(2*a))*sqrt(4*a**2*(start + b/(2*a))**2 + 1)/2 + asinh(2*a*(end + b/(2*a)))/(4*a) - asinh(2*a*(start + b/(2*a)))/(4*a)
```

Here, I can use the equation.

```
from sympy import solve, sqrt, asinh, nsolve
end = sp.S('end')
a = -1
b = 0
c = 4
w3 = 1
length = 2

eq = sp.Eq((end + b/(2*a))*sqrt(4*a**2*(end + b/(2*a))**2 + 1)/2 - (w3 + b/(2*a))*sqrt(4*a**2*(w3 + b/(2*a))**2 + 1)/2 + asinh(2*a*(end + b/(2*a)))/(4*a) - asinh(2*a*(w3 + b/(2*a)))/(4*a),length)
```

I found two ways to solve the equation.

1. Use nsolve. This gives only one answer even if I have two. For example, if there are two answers (a+sqrt(b), a-sqrt(b)), I guess this gives only one answer closer to expected_value_to_start_search_answer.

   print(sp.nsolve(eq, expected_value_to_start_search_answer))
2. Use solve. This gives all possible answers, but it is slower than the first option.

   sol = solve(eq,end)
   print(sol)

Answer (score 0):

Your target points `x, y` sit on the parabolic curve as well as on a circle around p1, in other words, all fulfill the equations

```
a x^2 + b x + c = y
(x - p1x)^2 + (y - p1y)^2 = r^2
```

You can simply eliminate `y` by inserting the lhs from the first equation into the second, and solve the resulting quadratic equation for `x`.